# Votes required to reach specific percentage

Tags: percentages, ratio

If the results of a poll with two options is `20% - 80%`, we can be certain that **at least** 5 people have voted, because the 20:80 ratio can't be reached with fewer than 5 people.

#### Question

- Is there any way to calculate how many votes are required to reach a given result? E.g if a vote ends `29,6% - 70,4%`, what is the minimum amount of votes that could produce this result?
- Is there any way to calculate this for polls with more than 2 options?

Comment: As with Batting Averages, it gets tricky if there is rounding.  For example if $2$ out of $7$ vote No then you'd have $28.571429\dots \%$ and $71.428571\dots\%$ which you would probably round to something like $28.57,\,71.43$.  But if you used those numbers you'd look at the fraction $\frac {2857}{10000}$ and, as that is in least terms, you'd deduce that you needed $10000$ voters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with Batting Averages, it gets tricky when there is rounding (which there usually is).  For example if $2$ out of $7$ vote for a certain thing, and the other $5$ vote against it,  then you'd have $28.571429\dots \%$ and $71.428571\dots\%$ which you would probably round to something like $28.57,\,71.43$.  But if you used those numbers you'd look at the fraction $\frac {2857}{10000}$ and, as that is in least terms, you'd deduce that you needed $10000$ voters.

One way to handle this is to use [Continued Fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction).  For example, the Continued Fractions expansion for $\frac {2857}{10000}$ has the terms $[0;3,1,1,1428]$ and of course $\frac 27$ is one of the convergents.

To illustrate using your values: starting from $.296$ we'd look at the convergents to the continued fraction for $\frac {296}{1000}=\frac {37}{125}$.  They are:  $$\{0, \frac 13, \frac 27, \frac 3{10}, \frac {5}{17}, \frac {8}{27}, \frac {37}{125}\}$$

Now...$\frac 5{17} \approx .29411\dots$ so that's unlikely.  However $\frac 8{27}=0.296296296296\dots $ so if you are rounding to the tenths place in the percent then this would work, so I'd argue that the answer here could well be $\boxed {27}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

for the $20\%-80\%$ case you have reduced the fraction
$$
\frac{20}{100} \rightarrow \frac{1}{5}
$$

do the same for your question

$$
\frac{296}{1000} \rightarrow ?
$$